# Make React load images from /public folder first

Tags: reactjs, frontend

React seems to always render images from an external URL first, followed by images from the public folder. Is there a way to force React to render images from public folder first?

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-diffie-etepwo?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Is it just happening on codesandbox or does it also happen on your local machine?

Comment: Do you mean at first the local image will load then replacing that the url image will load?